# How to use one method to populate DropDownList or AJAX ComboBox

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a single method that can populate either a DropDownList or an AJAX ComboBox (instead of having two separate, nearly identical methods) in C#. I pass the method a query string, the name of the text field, and the name of the value field, along with the dropdown object. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void BindDropDown(string selectCmd, string textField, string valueField, object ddList)
//Populate dropdown list (DropDownList or ComboBox)
{
    // var for dropdown object
    object _ddl = null;

    // Get type of dropdown
    if (ddList.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
    {
        _ddl = (DropDownList)ddList;
    }
    else if (ddList.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
    {
        _ddl = (ComboBox)ddList;
    }

    // Setup DB connection
    SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(LTConnStr);
    SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(selectCmd, dbConn);

    //Set dropdown list params
    _ddl.DataTextField = textField;
    _ddl.DataValueField = valueField;

    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        _ddl.DataSource = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
        _ddl.DataBind();
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConn.Close();
    }
} //end method BindDropDown
```

But I get the error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' ...". I've also tried the "is" syntax:

```
        // Get type of dropdown
        if (ddList is DropDownList)
        {
            _ddl = (DropDownList)ddList;
        }
        else if (ddList is ComboBox)
        {
            _ddl = (ComboBox)ddList;
        }
```

with the same result. I know I'm close, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Are you getting that error on one or the other, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_ddl` variable is of type object, the casts don't change that fact, so even after you have cast `ddList` to either a `DropDownList` or `ComboBox` you only have access to the methods/properties of the underlying `object` class.

Basically you should look for the class that they both inherit from that contains the methods that you need to use. This is the [ListControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.aspx) class.

You can then simply use:

```
ListControl _ddl = null;
```

In place of:

```
object _ddl = null;
```

Or you can do something like this when casting:

```
ListControl _ddl = null;
_ddl = ddList as DropDownList;
_ddl = (_ddl == null) ? ddList as ComboBox: _ddl;
if (_ddl == null) { return; }
```

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was missing. I thought that once you cast an object it becomes the type you cast it to. I've been programming in Visual C# for 6 years (no formal training, however, just "trial by fire") and I learn something new every day.

Comment: @timbck2 You may be thinking of [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), when you assign to it via something like `var _dll = ddList as DropDownList` it is implicitly signed with the type that the expression on the right is. However in your example `var` wouldn't work because you can't declare it without a type, so you wouldn't be able to use the same variable name for operations.

Comment: By the way, I discovered today that the same method can be applied to ListBox controls as well.

Comment: @timbck2 If you go to the link I provided you can see that: 
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedList`,
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList`,
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`,
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox`, and 
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList` all inherit from `ListControl`, so they can all be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this "object _ddl = null;" is causing the problem. Object does not expose the DataTextField property.

If you are using .net 4, you can change:

object _ddl = null;

to

dynamic _ddl = null;

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still on Visual Studio 2008, so that option isn't available to me.